# Java exception on starting thingsboard

Tags: java, spring, thingsboard

I tried installing thingsboard on my local Windows machine [according to the installtion guide on thingsboard.io](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/).

When I hit the `net start thingsboard` command, the application says that the server is successfully started.

Afterwards I can't open it on `http://localhost:8080`.

The `thingsboard.log` file says:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-18 10:11:46,636 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MqttTransportService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardServerApplication.main(ThingsboardServerApplication.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:363)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.safeExecute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:401)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:877)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In you stacktrace you see:

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

The port is already in use

Comment: so I should change the local port where thingsboard is running?

Comment: yes or stop the other process using the same port